# jQuery mobile does not add back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-application, jquery-mobile

My head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0 target-densitydpi=medium-dpi'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

    <!--jQuery, mobile options, JQM-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/css/main.css">
</head>
```

transition.js:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { 

    //back button
    $.mobile.page.prototype.addBackBtn = true;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) { $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none'; $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none'; } else {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'pop';
    } 
});
```

Why isn't it being added?

Comment: I think your call to `document.write()` ends up nesting two `<script>` elements. Your `window.jQuery || <include script>` pattern might not be viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that this snippet is AFTER jQuery library loads but BEFORE jQueryMobile library is loaded:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { 

    //back button
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) { $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none'; $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none'; } else {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'pop';
    } 
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Refer to: [jquery-mobile still "No Back Button" (Beta 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310070/jquery-mobile-still-no-back-button-beta-2)

Comment: It's `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn`. Without `.options`, it will not work.

Comment: That's exactly what Im doing. Also @FrédéricHamidi that doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Have you tried loading an older jquery library? 1.7 or 1.8. The newest one might need the migrate add-on.

Comment: Frédéric's solution works just fine, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Gajotres probably. But I leave the code included as the only Javascript code on and  it still doesn't work. Very strange.